# Is it possible to connect 2 networks with same IP range?

Tags: ip, ip-address, router

I have two networks with the same IP addresses in use and I need to connect them.

I have a third network between the two to connect them but I need to know :
 - is it possible to communicate iof the IP are the same on both side ?
 - Which technology to use to configure the router to achieve this ? Do I need NAT, or something else ?

Example :
I have network A in 192.168.1.0/24 with one machine 192.168.1.10
I have network B with the same configuration
I have a third network C in 192.168.222.0/24 connected to A and C with routeurs
How to access the machine on network A with the one on network C ?

Answer (score 7):

It's very, very ugly. The simplest way is to construct a bridging network with two routers in it, with those two routers connected in the bridging network.

Each bridging router NATs `192.168.1.0/24` to a different /24 inside the bridging network. Assuming `192.168.10.0/24`, `192.168.11.0/24`, `192.168.3.0/24` are free and `192.168.1.251` is free in each network:

Router 1 works as follows:

1. Router 1 is assigned IP address `192.168.3.1/24` in the bridging network and `192.168.1.251` in its own network.
2. Router 1 has a connection to one of the `192.168.1.0/24` networks and NATs `192.168.1.x` to and from `192.168.10.x`
3. Router 1 has a route for `192.168.11.0/24` with a next hop of `192.168.3.2` in the bridging network.

Router 2 works as follows:

1. Router 2 is assigned IP address 192.168.3.2/24 in the bridging network and `192.168.1.251` in its own network.
2. Router 2 has a connection to the other of the `192.168.1.0/24` networks and NATs `192.168.1.x` to and from `192.168.11.x`.
3. Router 2 has a route for `192.168.10.0/24` with a next hop of `192.168.3.1` in the bridging network.

In this way, machines on the `192.168.1.0/24` network connected to router 1 can access machines in the second network by using `192.168.11.0` addresses. Vice-versa for the other network, using `192.168.10.0` addresses.

The default router in each network must be configured to route packets for 192.168.10.0/24 and 192.168.11.0/24 to `192.168.1.251`. The routers can be cheap wireless routers running OpenWRT, Tomato, or DD-WRT. These routers can also be used for other purposes. For example, if they're already the default router for their `192.168.1.0/24` network, the configuration is slightly simpler.

While it should be possible to do this with a single router using both SNAT and DNAT, I've never gotten it to work. Others I know have reported similar issues. I believe it's because the ARP system can't handle two distinct ARP entries for the same IP on distinct interfaces.